# What's the best way to change a global component based on the current route?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-router

I'm building a website with React and I would like my navbar to have a different background color depending on the current route. My App.js looks like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <div className="Navbar" >
            <Navbar />
          </div>
          <div className="Content">
            <Route path="/" exact render={() => <LandingPage />} />
            <Route path="/about" exact render={() => <AboutPage />} />
            <Route path="/contact" exact render={() => <ContactPage />} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Suppose I want a transparent background on the Home ("/") page, but a solid color everywhere else, what is the best way to go about changing the `background` property in `<Navbar />`'s CSS to achieve what I want?

Suppose I stored the CSS properties I'd like to change in `this.state`, and then call a function to change these whenever there is a route change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use context api for changing the background color of any of your components. So, you just need to define a context value based on the different urls.